# Python dictionary - value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an `if` <strike>block</strike> statement that is checking if a string that I have assigned to variable `movieTitle` contains the value of a key-value pair in a predefined dictionary.

The code I have is:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

leaveOut = {
            'a':'cat',
            'b':'dog',
            'c':'werewolf',
            'd':'vampire',
            'e':'nightmare'
            }

br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open("http://<a_website_containing_a_list_of_movie_titles/")
html = r.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    # Find all table data
    for data in row.find_all('td'):
        code_handling_the_assignment_of_movie_title_to_var_movieTitle

        if any(movieTitle.find(leaveOut[c]) < 1 for c in 'abcde'):
            do_this_set_of_instructions
        else:
             pass
```

<strike>My thoughts are that I can test the string `movieTitle` for any of the values of the dictionary (predefined) by using the `.find()` method, which if the value is found will return an index integer value of greater than (or at least) equal to 1. Therefore if the result of the condition is <1 (usually -1 when absent) I can continue with the rest of the program, otherwise not perform the rest of the program.</strike>

<strike>However, when I use the Aptana debug feature I can see that my breakpoint on this `if` block are never engaged, as if Aptana is skipping right over it. Why is this?</strike>

Edit:

Have included more code for clarity. Having reviewed the suggestions I have used the code that @kqr suggested. However, my actual program still displays movieTitle despite having string values contained in leaveOut dict. Why?

Comment: Do you really want to be using bitwise or (`|`) instead of logical or (`or`)?

Comment: Also, maybe `any(movieTitle.find(leaveOut[c]) < 1 for c in 'abcdefghijklm')` would probably be more succinct.

Comment: This returns True consistently, regardless of whether the value of the dict is found in `movieTitle` or not hence why the `if` block is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you confirm exactly what you're trying to achieve here?  You're trying to execute a set of instructions if ANY of the values in the `leaveOut` dictionary is NOT present in the movieTitle?  If so:

```
if [x for x in leaveOut.values() if x not in movieTitle]:
```

would be more concise.  Also, if you're going to use the formulation above then the comparator has to be `0` rather than `1` otherwise matches at the first character will fire the set of instructions.

Comment: Basically I have a dictionary with key-value pairs as per usual. Before getting to the `if` block in my original post I am using BeautifulSoup in my actual program to assign a string from a webpage to variable `movieTitle` (in my post I specify that I scrape a movie title and assign that as a string). What I am trying to achieve is: 1. check if any value I have in my dict is present in the string, 2. if yes then skip over the instructions. `do_this_set_of_instructions`.

Comment: "Also, if you're going to use the formulation above then the comparator has to be 0 rather than 1 otherwise matches at the first character will fire the set of instructions" I'm not following. Isn't the find() method going to find only the exact word I've specified in the dict?

Comment: thanks, in that case i think this will do the trick.  the second point i was making is basically that `"hello world".find("hello")` returns `0` as arrays are zero-indexed in python.  If your if clause fires on any `find` that comes back as `<1` then it will execute the instructions for matches at the very start of the `movieTitle` string as well as anything that's not found at all (and thus returns `-1`).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I have updated my code to show you what I was trying to achieve. Make more sense?

Answer (score 3):

You can do as Captain Skyhawk suggests, or you can replace your entire `if` condition with:

```
if any(movieTitle.find(leaveOut[c]) < 1
       for c in 'abcdefghijklm'):
```

As for your second question, are you sure you don't mean

```
if not any(movieTitle.find(leaveOut[c]) < 1
           for c in 'abcdefghijklm'):
```

Comment: This would be MUCH better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using 'or'. It appears you're using a binary or( the | character).

For example:

```
if ((movieTitle.find(leaveOut['a']) < 1) or
    (movieTitle.find(leaveOut['b']) < 1) or
    (movieTitle.find(leaveOut['c']) < 1) or ....
```