# Search a string for values present in a dict

Tags: python

As the title suggests, I am trying to find values in a dict within a string. This relates to my post here: [Python dictionary - value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050524/python-dictionary-value)

My code is something like follows:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

leaveOut = {
            'a':'cat',
            'b':'dog',
            'c':'werewolf',
            'd':'vampire',
            'e':'nightmare'
            }

br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open("http://<a_website_containing_a_list_of_movie_titles/")
html = r.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    # Find all table data
    for data in row.find_all('td'):
        code_handling_the_assignment_of_movie_title_to_var_movieTitle

        if any(movieTitle.find(leaveOut[c]) < 1 for c in 'abcde'):
            do_this_set_of_instructions
        else:
             pass
```

I want to skip the program contained under the `if` block (identified above as `do_this_set_of_instructions`) if the string stored in `movieTitle` contains any of the strings (or values if you like) in the `leaveOut` dict.

So far, I have had no luck with `any(movieTitle.find(leaveOut[c]) < 1 for c in 'abcde'):` as it always returns True and the do_this_set_of_instructions always execute regardless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` returns `-1` if the substring isn't in the string that you're working on, so your `any()` call will return `True` if any of the words *aren't* in the title.

You may want to do something like this instead:

```
 if any(leaveOut[c] in movieTitle for c in 'abcde'):
     # One of the words was in the title
```

Or the opposite:

```
 if all(leaveOut[c] not in movieTitle for c in 'abcde'):
     # None of the words were in the title
```

Also, why are you using a dictionary like this? Why don't you just store the words in a list?

```
leave_out = ['dog', 'cat', 'wolf']

...

if all(word not in movieTitle for word in leave_out):
     # None of the words were in the title
```

Comment: Thank you, the list option works for me. I tried to do it with a dict due to an error I had earlier so I thought a dict would have been a workaround...

Comment: BTW, is this case-sensitive? For instance if a substring in the variable `movieTitle` was "cat" but I specified "Cat" in my list, would this still be identified or would I need both "Cat" and "cat" in my list?

Comment: @I_lost_my_last_account: Use ` movieTitle.lower()` in place of `movieTitle` in the generator.